# AttributeError: module 'glm' has no attribute 'perspective'

Tags: python, attributeerror

i dont know what happened

i thought it would work because it works in every single other computer exept this   pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.11.7)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects\OPEN3D\main.py", line 40, in <module>
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects\OPEN3D\main.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.camera = Camera(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects\OPEN3D\camera.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.m_proj = self.get_projection_matrix()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects\OPEN3D\camera.py", line 13, in get_projection_matrix
    return glm.perspective(glm.radians(FOV),self.aspect_ratio,Near,Far)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'glm' has no attribute 'perspective'
PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects'; & 'c:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe' 'c:\Users\Dell\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2023.3.13341008-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '58277' '--' 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\projects\OPEN3D\main.py'
```

please anyone help me

Comment: Please do not share you contact information on [SO].

Comment: It would help to know what the `glm` module is. Or what other modules you are using.

Comment: Please explain how do you expect us to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Are you sure you [installed glm](https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyGLM?tab=readme-ov-file#types-and-functions-are-not-available-after-installing-from-the-pypi-using-pip-install-glm) correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It might be probably because you have downloaded and installed glm - which is a different library, instead of PyGLM.

So try uninstalling glm:

```
pip uninstall glm
```

And try installing PyGLM:

```
pip install numpy PyGLM
```